# Import empty string(column default value) instead of NULL value when using bcp utility with a external data file and format file

Tags: sql-server, bcp, data-import

I have a small issue with using bcp import tool. This is the case I have a .csv data file (field separator if | character) and format file. I can import data into the table successfully, but it is importing NULL value instead of empty strings in data file. consider below as sample record in data file

```
col1|col2|||col5|col6
```

I got output like below

```
col1 col2 NULL NULL col5 col6
```

but I am expecting below output

```
col1 col2  (empty string) (empty string) col5 col6
```

in my table definition, default values are empty string, is this due to an issue with data file (bcp data exporting command) or my data importing bcp command.

this is the command I used to import data
bcp [database].[table] in M:\data\xx.csv -f M:\format\XX.FMT -S serverName -T

Thanks and All reply are welcome.

Comment: I don't know your tool but it seems it creates INSERT INTO statements where it creates NULL values for not given values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to create the column of the table to have default value empty string ""

For example:

```
create table mytable (
  col1 varchar(10) default ""
)
```

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008 and its tools to create and modify tables. I put nothing for default value attribute(Default value or Binding) for each column and NULL allowed.

Comment: If the column definition can not be changed to have default value empty string, then you can bcp the file to a staging table and then do an insert to the main table where the insert can use empty string

Comment: Thanks Mark, Actually this time I checked the possibility to continue with NULL values. As there is no problem with NULL values I did it as it is because it is a reason to consume additional time by adding another table for BCP import due to it is a small part of a DB job.

Answer (score 0):

You can update from the interface in management studio In the editor properties of the column Default Value or Binding : 
    (' ')